# select statement returns 'table does not exist' error but it does

Tags: mysql

I have a table t1 in MySQL that has the field/columns ex1, ex2.
Another table t2 has field ex3 and ex4.

I want to select the rows from ex1 and ex3 where ex2 equals ex4. This is my syntax:

`SELECT ex1, ex2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.ex2=t2.ex4`

I thought this should work, but I get an error saying: 
`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't2.ex4' in 'where clause'`.

I checked for spelling/case mistakes, so that's not the issue.

There is another question with the same issue. However, I did not copy databases and can't seem to find solace in that answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try SELECT t1.ex1, t1.ex2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.ex2=t2.ex4 too? Also, could you provide export the create of tables

Comment: I did try that, but get the same error. thanks.

Comment: I have updated my ubuntu and removed the workbench because it was giving some startup errors and now it's working again on the command line...